# Rowspan for every 7 results from database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make `rowspan='7'` for every next 7 results from database. 
I did it for first 7 results with code:

```
                 <?php if(0==$rowspan++) {
                    echo "<td align='center' class='hide-from-screen' rowspan='7'><font color='red'>test</font></td>";
                 }
                  ?>

                <td align='center' class='hide-from-screen'><font color="red">test</font></td>
```

I have set `$rowspan = 0;` before while loop.

Result looks like this:

[image]

How can I make `rowspan='7'` for next 50 upcoming results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php if($rowspan++ % 7 == 0) {
          echo "<td align='center' class='hide-from-screen' rowspan='7'><font color='red'>test</font></td>";
       }
?>
```

and remove the other `<td>` from the html.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Few of my results are torn off after the rest goes to the new page on the print. What you mean by "remove the other <td>"

Comment: I meant this one: `<td align='center' class='hide-from-screen'><font color="red">test</font></td>`; it is not required with the code to print a <td> every 7 rows.

Comment: Okay I get it. Let me try

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hey sir, about that rowspan, how can I make it standing down at 7th place like this: https://imgur.com/a/lpP6UyN

Comment: You could try using CSS: add  `style="vertical-align: bottom"` to the `<td>` element.

Comment: Yeah but It will show me only at bottom of that currently <td>.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I don't properly understand what you mean?

Comment: I'm looking at it but I don't understand what the green circle and arrow mean. If you just want to move the 1389.78 value why can't you move it with CSS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177790/discussion-between-pablo-and-nick).